# how to get url request/response count of webapp deployed in Tomcat

Tags: web-services, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

i am deploying my web application which contains images or files on the tomcat 1.7.I want to measure the url request count for these images/files in my web app.Is there any configurations/any plugins available to measure this in Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no APIs that let you do that.  But you've always got the traffic logs (in the [root]/logs/ directory).  Where/if you've got traffic logging enabled is controlled in server.xml -- search for `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"`.  As long as you don't need this data in real time, that's probably the way to go.

Comment: Is it possible to get exact user(successive user browsing) count?

Comment: @santro not that I'm aware of, but if you're logging user-agent, a hash of that and the client's host address would give you a pretty good approximation of unique users.  Not a perfect solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It's a webapp you deploy to your container that gives you details about the other web apps in there.  Request count is one of the metrics.

http://www.lambdaprobe.org/